# Teams channel messages posted by Webhook connector only shows the first line

Tags: microsoft-teams

This is a very strange issue we are having. We have a data processing service that posts a message to Teams channel using webhook every night. Everything was working fine until few days ago. The full message used to show up in the channel conversations.

But now the channel shows only the first line of the post. Please see the attached screenshot.  All the previous posts from months ago also show only one line. This only happens on the desktop client and web portal.
The Teams app on both Android and iOS displays the full message, which is usually 7-8 lines long.

If I click on "New Conversation" and paste the same 7-8 lines it does show full message.

I have sifted through all settings of the desktop client and cannot find a solution. Cleared all caches also without success.

Appreciate any help.

Thank you[image: screen shot of message]

Edit - 12-9-22
Please see the JSON code below, but this is happening with older messages as well, that were posted months ago, which used to display fully. So I am guessing this has nothing to do with JSON itself and has to do with channel/chat window settings. As I mentioned before the posts show fully on both Android and IOS apps.

```
    public async void SendTeamsMessage(string body, string projectName) {
        string webhookUrl = MailSettings.Current.TeamsWebHookURL;
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webhookUrl);
        TeamsMessage message = new TeamsMessage();
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("Batch " + batch.BatchId.ToString() + " finished processing.");sb.AppendLine("Alert - " + projectName);
        sb.AppendLine("Message from Service at " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\r\n");
        sb.AppendLine("Message :" + body);
        message.text = sb.ToString();
        string serializeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
        System.Net.Http.StringContent content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(serializeJson, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content);
    }

    private class TeamsMessage {
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what happened, but we can see the full messages now. Started working few minutes ago.